# Adding a Field value in a table to a value in other table

Tags: sql

First of all many thanks to all who are trying to solve many issues all over the world.
Now I too have a small issue and I hope it can be answered easily.

I have 2 Tables as below.

```
**Table-1**
Emp_ID
Emp_Name
Emp_Address
Emp_Deliveries

**Table-2**
Order_ID
Order_Date
Emp_ID
Delivery_Date
Delivery_Status
```

Table 2 Contains all the deliveries information and Table-1 Contains the Employee Master Data.
Now I want to add the count of deliveries done by each employee in table 2 to the Emp_Deliveries field in table-1.
For Example Emp10001 has a value of 3 in Emp_Deliveries fielld I table-1 and now he has delivered 2 orders which is available in table-2, I want to add those 2 to Emp_Deliveries field in table-1. Can you please help me out with this scenario.

Comment: How do you determine if the orders in table-2 have not been added already to the Emp-Deliveries value?

Comment: The table-2 contains only the information about fresh deliveries. This is a temporary table which will be archieved immediatly after this addition.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a `select`:

```
select e.emp_id, (e.emp_deliveries + coalesce(d.cnt, 0)) as emp_deliveries
from table1 e left outer join
     (select emp_id, count(*) as cnt
      from table2 d
      group by emp_id
     ) d
     on e.emp_id = d.emp_id;
```

If you want to actually update the values:

```
update table1
    set emp_deliveries = (emp_deliveries +
                          (select count(*)
                           from table2
                           where table2.emp_id = table1.emp_id
                          ));
```

There are other ways to phrase these queries (particularly the second one).  But these are standard SQL so should work in any database.

Comment: Hi Gordon Many thanks for your solution. It is working fine. But i have a small problem here. Is it possible to update table-1 by adding value of a field(Product_Count) in table-2 to (Emp_Deliveries) in table-1 when t1.Emp_ID=t2.Emp_ID. Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Subash . . . If you have a product count field in table2, then use `sum(product_count)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon..I tried the way you suggested but with failure. Actually the Product_Count in table-2 is per employee. For example an employee can deliver 2 products in a single delivery. So am looking for a solution to Add No of products delivered by an employee and add to the existing in table-1.

Comment: Sorry if i confused you with my initial question..The one which i sent now is the actual requirement.